# How-to: install all packages from DVD when setting-up an RHEL server (text mode)?

Tags: package-management, redhat, provisioning

I have tried googling, and so far have found nothing.

Is there a way to select ***all*** packages from the install DVD for Red Hat Enterprise Linux when doing an installation?

With the GUI installer, I know it is possible to customize each group selected. Is it also possible in the text-mode installer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After several hours of digging, I cannot find such a way to do an `@Everything` in the text-mode installer.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. I think it's pretty obvious too. It's been a while since I did a install without kickstart though so maybe someone can elaborate.

Comment: last time I did it and it was "obvious" was with Red Hat 6.something waay back in the day :)

Comment: 6 or 7 sounds about right. It's been a while. I'd suggest just run through the installer and see what you get. In kickstart you can add @everything to install all pkgs. I generally do the opposite and install a minimal selection. :)

Comment: I've been through the installer manually and see no way of doing it outside of the gui edition and going into each subgroup and selecting all